# Creating static permanent hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4
Ruby 2.5
```

I have some static data in a table, that get called often. The data in that table does not change in between application updates.

Is there a way to create a hash from that table, and have it be permanent to be used across different sessions?

## Edit:

Obviously, this can be defined as a constant, BUT, there's a lot of data in there, and the objective, is to allow the admins, to make modifications to the data, through a dashboard, during regular maintenance, otherwise, a programmer and testing are required if it's done through a constant (not to mention the amount of data)

Comment: Why store it in a table at all? Why not hardcode as a simple constant?

Comment: It's a fairly significant amount of data, and it's in a table, to make it easier for non-programmer admins to modify the data on quarterly basis, when the app is down for maitenance

Comment: could it be in a yml file loaded as a constant on App launch? Kind of like how the Config gem (https://github.com/railsconfig/config) does it already